# How to show tooltip on the dynamic images using KineticJS

Tags: kineticjs

I want to show the tooltip on the dynamic images inside the canvas. Here is path of the image on which I want to show the tooltip.(I want to show the tooltip on the Green and Gray images).
[enter link description here](http://i41.tinypic.com/t7zsbn.jpg)

Here is my code I am using to do the so with the help of kinetic.js.

```
 $("#tabs li").each(function () {
            $(this).live("click", function () {
                var tabname = $(this).find("a").attr('name');
                tabname = $.trim(tabname.replace("#tab", ""));
                var tabId = $(this).find("a").attr('href');
                tabId = $.trim(tabId.replace("#", ""));

                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Home/GetTabsDetail",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    type: 'GET',
                    data: { tabId: tabId },
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (data) {
                        var bayStatus = [];
                        var i = 0;
                        var image_array = [];
                        var BayExist = false;
                        var BayCondition;
                        var imgSrc;
                        var CanvasBacgroundImage;
                        var _X;
                        var _bayNumber;
                        var _Y;
                        var _ZoneName;
                        $(data).each(function (i, val) {
                            i = i + 1;
                            if (!BayExist) {
                                bayStatus = val.BayStatus;
                                CanvasBacgroundImage = val.TabImageLocation;
                                BayExist = true;
                            }
                            $.each(val, function (k, v) {
                                if (k == "BayNumber") {
                                    BayCondition = bayStatus[v];
                                    _bayNumber = v;
                                    if (BayCondition == "O")
                                        imgSrc = "../../images/Parking/OccupiedCar.gif"
                                    else if (BayCondition == "N")
                                        imgSrc = "../../images/Parking/OpenCar.gif";
                                }
                                if (k == "BayX")
                                    _X = v;
                                if (k == "BayY")
                                    _Y = v;
                                if (k == "ZoneName")
                                    _ZoneName = v;
                            });
                            image_array.push({ img: imgSrc, xAxis: _X, yAxis: _Y, toolTip: _bayNumber, ZoneName: _ZoneName });
                        });
                        var imageUrl = CanvasBacgroundImage;

                        $('#tab' + tabId).css('background-image', 'url("../../images/Parking/' + imageUrl + '")');
                        var _timer = setInterval(function () {
                            var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
                                container: 'tab' + tabId,
                                width: 700,
                                height: 308
                            });
                            var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
                            var planetOverlay;
                            function writeMessage(message) {
                                text.setText(message);
                                layer.draw();
                            }
                            var text = new Kinetic.Text({
                                x: 140,
                                y: 0,
                                fontFamily: 'Arial',
                                fontSize: 20,

                                text: '',
                                fill: '#000',
                                width: 740,
                                height: 60,
                                align: 'left',
                                padding: 40,


                            });
                            for (i = 0; i < image_array.length; i++) {
                                img = new Image();
                                debugger;
                                img.src = image_array[i].img;
                                planetOverlay = new Kinetic.Image({
                                    x: image_array[i].xAxis,
                                    y: image_array[i].yAxis,
                                    image: img,
                                    height: 18,
                                    width: 18,
                                    id: image_array[i].toolTip,
                                    name: image_array[i].ZoneName
                                });

                                planetOverlay.on('mouseover', function () {
                                    writeMessage("Bay: " + this.getId() + " , Zone: " + this.getName());
                                });
                                planetOverlay.on('mouseout', function () {
                                    writeMessage('');
                                });
                                planetOverlay.createImageHitRegion(function () {
                                    layer.draw();
                                });

                                layer.add(planetOverlay);
                                layer.add(text);
                                stage.add(layer);
                            }

                            clearInterval(_timer);
                            //$("#tab3 .kineticjs-content").find("canvas").css('background-image', 'url("' + imageUrl + '")');
                        }, 1000)


                    },
                    error: function (result) {
                        alert('error');
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

Here is the html section for this.

```
<div style="background-position: center center; margin: 0px auto; padding-top: 50px; background-repeat: no-repeat; width: 700px; height: 308px; display: block; background-image: url(&quot;../../images/Parking/Garage-Floor-Plan.png&quot;);" id="tab3"><div style="position: relative; display: inline-block; width: 700px; height: 308px;" class="kineticjs-content" role="presentation"><canvas style="padding: 0px; margin: 0px; border: 0px none; background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 700px; height: 308px;" width="700" height="308"></canvas></div></div>
```

This above mentioned code is working now for single message to be shown on every image mouseover but on the mentioed co-oridinates , Here I want to show the unique message on mouseover of every single image(Green/Gray in the pic) as in given pic and just above the images I want to show the tooltip.

Moreover it takes double clicks  to bind the images to canvas  of the tab.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: I'm having trouble following your code logic. Your setInterval is repeatedly (every 200ms) loading the same group of images and creating kinetic.images from those images.  Why repeat...and that's too much to ask in 200ms.

Comment: Alter the code as you need to make it work. As per your statement you meant is Kinetic is also generating the images ?. I need to implement tooltip over the images in the given picture.Any Suggestions are most welcome.

Comment: The code is modified now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The modified code is under below which is working now as required.I managed to do that with the help of kinecticjs and Opentip. Here is the output pic [here](http://tinypic.com/r/mrv0pk/5).

```
$("#tabs li").each(function () {
            $(this).live("click", function () {
                var tabname = $(this).find("a").attr('name');
                tabname = $.trim(tabname.replace("#tab", ""));
                var tabId = $(this).find("a").attr('href');
                tabId = $.trim(tabId.replace("#", ""));
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Home/GetTabsDetail",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    type: 'GET',
                    data: { tabId: tabId },
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (data) {
                        var bayStatus = [];
                        var i = 0;
                        var image_array = [];
                        var BayExist = false;
                        var BayCondition;
                        var imgSrc;
                        var CanvasBacgroundImage;
                        var _X;
                        var _bayNumber;
                        var _Y;
                        var _ZoneName;
                        $(data).each(function (i, val) {
                            i = i + 1;
                            if (!BayExist) {
                                bayStatus = val.BayStatus;
                                CanvasBacgroundImage = val.TabImageLocation;
                                BayExist = true;
                            }
                            $.each(val, function (k, v) {
                                if (k == "BayNumber") {
                                    BayCondition = bayStatus[v];
                                    _bayNumber = v;
                                    if (BayCondition == "O")
                                        imgSrc = "../../images/Parking/OccupiedCar.gif"
                                    else if (BayCondition == "N")
                                        imgSrc = "../../images/Parking/OpenCar.gif";
                                }
                                if (k == "BayX")
                                    _X = v;
                                if (k == "BayY")
                                    _Y = v;
                                if (k == "ZoneName")
                                    _ZoneName = v;
                            });
                            image_array.push({ img: imgSrc, xAxis: _X, yAxis: _Y, toolTip: _bayNumber, ZoneName: _ZoneName });
                        });
                        var imageUrl = CanvasBacgroundImage;
                        $('#tab' + tabId).css('background-image', 'url("../../images/Parking/' + imageUrl + '")');
                        var _timer = setInterval(function () {
                            var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
                                container: 'tab' + tabId,
                                width: 700,
                                height: 308
                            });
                            var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
                            var planetOverlay;
                            function writeMessage(message, _x, _y) {
                                text.setX(_x + 20);
                                text.setY(_y + 1);
                                text.setText(message);
                                layer.draw();
                            }
                            var text = new Kinetic.Text({
                                fontFamily: 'Arial',
                                fontSize: 14,
                                text: '',
                                fill: '#000',
                                width: 200,
                                height: 60,
                                align: 'center'

                            });
                            var opentooltip = new Opentip(
                                "div#tab" + tabId, //target element 
                                "dummy", // will be replaced
                                "", // title
                                {
                                showOn: null // I'll manually manage the showOn effect
                            });
                            Opentip.styles.win = {
                                borderColor: "black",
                                shadow: false,
                                background: "#EAEAEA"
                            };
                            Opentip.defaultStyle = "win";
                            for (i = 0; i < image_array.length; i++) {
                                img = new Image();
                                debugger;
                                img.src = image_array[i].img;
                                planetOverlay = new Kinetic.Image({
                                    x: image_array[i].xAxis,
                                    y: image_array[i].yAxis,
                                    image: img,
                                    height: 18,
                                    width: 18,
                                    id: image_array[i].toolTip,
                                    name: image_array[i].ZoneName
                                });
                                planetOverlay.on('mouseover', function () {
                                    opentooltip.setContent("<span style='color:#25A0D3;'>Bay:</span> " + this.getId() + "<br> <span style='color:#25A0D3;'>Zone:</span><span>" + this.getName() + "</span>");
                                    //writeMessage("Bay: " + this.getId() + " , Zone: " + this.getName(), this.getX(), this.getY());//other way of showing tooltip
                                    opentooltip.show();
                                    //$("#opentip-1").offset({ left: this.getX(), top: this.getY() });
                                });
                                planetOverlay.on('mouseout', function () {
                                    opentooltip.hide();
                                    // writeMessage('');
                                });
                                planetOverlay.createImageHitRegion(function () {
                                    layer.draw();
                                });
                                layer.add(planetOverlay);
                                layer.add(text);
                                stage.add(layer);
                            }
                            clearInterval(_timer);
                            //$("#tab3 .kineticjs-content").find("canvas").css('background-image', 'url("' + imageUrl + '")');
                        }, 1000)
                    },
                    error: function (result) {
                        alert('error');
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of that crazy confusing script. Why don't you just use plain JavaScript?
It is best if you paint your canvas in the correct order.
Here is a simple Demo of what I think you are looking for. 
Feel free to edit the code and add Functionality:
Live Demo:
[Codepen Demo](http://codepen.io/schoening/full/qcJxE)

Click the Edit button and take a look into the code.

Or check out the code here:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
canvas.width = 500;
canvas.width = 500;
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');



var image1 = new Image();
image1.onload = function() {
        // Image is Loaded, let's start the render() function!
        render();
};
image1.src = 'http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/darth-vader.jpg';

// Global X and Y from the MouseMove - to check if hovering over Vader
var x = 0, y = 0;
// This is a Simple Timeout. Since you want to re-draw the image often.
function render(){
  // Lets pain the Canvas Grey!
  ctx.fillStyle='grey';
  ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);

  // Draw Vader
  ctx.drawImage(image1, 200, 20, 200, 200);

  // These are roughly the positions of VADER, now the text will only display when you move over VADER!
  if(x > 275 && x < 540 && y > 35 && y < 210){
    ctx.fillStyle= 'black';
    ctx.fillRect(200,20,80,40);

    ctx.fillStyle= 'white';
    ctx.font="20px Georgia";
    ctx.fillText("VADER",205,45);
  }

  // Repeat every 200ms
  setTimeout(function(){
     render();
  },200);
}

window.addEventListener( 'mousemove', check_mouse_position);

// When the mouse is moved, it will call the function below:
function check_mouse_position(e){
  x = e.x;
  y = e.y;
}
```

This should be a lot simpler. Use the X and Y position of the Mouse to find out where to display your texts...

Comment: Hi Schoening thanks for your help. The code is now modified can you please have a look once. Here now this code is working fine just it takes two clicks to bind the image to the stage layer and more I would like now to show the tooltip over the images instead at some fixed x,y as it working now.

Comment: All you have to do is set the X and Y to the correct positions.
Just change them on updates or whatever dude. Like: make two global variables for X and Y and change their values to the correct position on your updates

Comment: Ok. Thanks . And how to make it work on the single click of the li tab currently it is working on two clicks on the tab I had given the interval though but still images are not getting bind to stage layer on one click . Would you mind helping me for this.?